# Embedded ActiveMQ Artemis doesn't show web console

Tags: java, activemq-artemis, hawtio

I am a junior Java developer, and I made a simple sample of embedded ActiveMQ Artemis programmatic. It works correctly, but I want to monitor it on my browser on `http://localost:8161` (like ActiveMQ Artemis that I install and run standalone). However, in embedded mode it didn't give me the web console, and I can't find any correct sample on any where to see it. Somewhere people say about Hawtio, JMX, and other ways but they didn't work correctly. Can somebody give a simple demo to me please?

JMX Hawtio and other things didn't work.

This is my simple class :

```java
import org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.config.impl.ConfigurationImpl;
import org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.embedded.EmbeddedActiveMQ;

public class EmbeddedActiveMq {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        ConfigurationImpl config = new ConfigurationImpl()
                .addAcceptorConfiguration("in-vm", "vm://0")
                .addAcceptorConfiguration("tcp", "tcp://localhost:61616")
                .setJMXManagementEnabled(true);

        EmbeddedActiveMQ server = new EmbeddedActiveMQ();
        server.setConfiguration(config);

        server.start();
        System.out.println("artemis is ok");
        while (true) {

        }
    }
}
```

These are my dependencies:

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>artemis-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.16.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>artemis-jms-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.16.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>artemis-jms-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.16.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jolokia</groupId>
        <artifactId>jolokia-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>artemis-core-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.17.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>artemis-web</artifactId>
        <version>2.29.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.hawt</groupId>
        <artifactId>hawtio-default</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.0</version>
        <type>war</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Update:

I used your solution, Mr. Bertram, and now I have a little problem. It listens on port `8161`, but it seems I did something wrong:

[image]

[image]

For `pathToArtemis` i use this path:
`.m2/repository/org/apache/activemq/artemis-server/2.16.0/artemis-server-2.16.0.jar`
and this path :
`.m2/repository/org/apache/activemq/artemis-web/2.16.0/artemis-web-2.16.0.jar` and the installation directory of `artemis`, but none of them did work, and I get nothing in panel.

Comment: first of all thanks for your help . i want to run a simple embedded programmatic artemis first . this is my simple class :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enable the management console via an embedded instance of Jetty managed by the broker using the following code:

```java
System.setProperty("hawtio.realm", "hawtio");
System.setProperty("hawtio.role", "myRole");
System.setProperty("hawtio.rolePrincipalClasses", "org.apache.activemq.artemis.spi.core.security.jaas.RolePrincipal");
System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config", "/path/to/login.config");
String pathToArtemis = "/path/to/artemis";
ConfigurationImpl config = new ConfigurationImpl()
        .addAcceptorConfiguration("in-vm", "vm://0")
        .addAcceptorConfiguration("tcp", "tcp://localhost:61616")
        .setJMXManagementEnabled(true);
EmbeddedActiveMQ server = new EmbeddedActiveMQ();
server.setMbeanServer(ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer());
server.start();
WebServerComponent webServerComponent = new WebServerComponent();
WebServerDTO webServerDTO = new WebServerDTO();
webServerDTO.path = "web";
BindingDTO bindingDTO = new BindingDTO();
bindingDTO.uri = "http://localhost:8161";
AppDTO branding = new AppDTO();
branding.name = "branding";
branding.url = "activemq-branding";
branding.war = "activemq-branding.war";
AppDTO plugin = new AppDTO();
plugin.name = "plugin";
plugin.url = "artemis-plugin";
plugin.war = "artemis-plugin.war";
AppDTO console = new AppDTO();
console.name = "console";
console.url = "console";
console.war = "console.war";
bindingDTO.addApp(branding);
bindingDTO.addApp(plugin);
bindingDTO.addApp(console);
webServerDTO.addBinding(bindingDTO);
ActiveMQSecurityManager securityManager = server.getActiveMQServer().getSecurityManager();
ManagementContextDTO managementDTO = new ManagementContextDTO();
ManagementContext managementContext = ManagementFactory.create(managementDTO, securityManager);
server.getActiveMQServer().getManagementService().registerHawtioSecurity(managementContext.getArtemisMBeanServerGuard());
webServerComponent.configure(webServerDTO, pathToArtemis, pathToArtemis);
server.getActiveMQServer().addExternalComponent(webServerComponent, true);
```

Your `login.config` might look something like this:

```
hawtio {
   org.apache.activemq.artemis.spi.core.security.jaas.PropertiesLoginModule required
       debug=false
       reload=true
       org.apache.activemq.jaas.properties.user="hawtio-users.properties"
       org.apache.activemq.jaas.properties.role="hawtio-roles.properties";
};
```

`hawtio-users.properties`:

```
myUser=myPass
```

`hawtio-roles.properties`:

```
myRole=myUser
```

Then you can login to the console at `http://localhost:8161/console` with the user `myUser` and the password `myPass`.

Lastly, I believe you can simplify your dependencies down to this:

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>artemis-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.16.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: I have used your solution but I had a little problem with it. I updated my question . with two pictures.Is it possible for you to answer my question please?

Comment: I updated my answer with code which should solve the problem explained in your update.