# Running an Artemis web console with security disabled?

Tags: activemq-artemis

I was looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76689316/3813411) response and it was very helpful in getting me set up with an Artemis web console with an embedded broker. However, I have security disabled on this broker with `security-enabled: false`, and I can't seem to figure out how to get the web console to not show a login page. It seems that I must specify a `java.security.auth.login.config`. Is it possible to make it such that there is no login page (and security not be enabled on the broker)?

I was thinking of perhaps using the [GuestLoginModule](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/security.html#jaas-login-modules) from the docs, but it says "Normally, the guest login module is chained with another login module, such as a properties login module." So I wasn't sure if that's the best route. It also felt a bit strange to me to add that since I should be running with security disabled. However this will still require a user to be presented with the login screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Apache ActiveMQ Artemis web console is based on [Hawtio](https://hawtio.github.io/hawtio) and use [the management API](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/management.html#the-management-api) to interact with broker. To disable the security of the web console you need to disable hawtio authentication and add all management beans to the allow list, i.e.

Add the following system property to the `JAVA_ARGS` variable in the `artemis.profile` file to disable hawtio authentication:

```
-Dhawtio.authenticationEnabled=false
```

Add the following entry to the management allow list in the `management.xml` file to add all management beans to the allow list:

```
<entry domain="*"/>
```

Answer (score -2):

Edit your broker.xml file, setting security-enabled to false. Be aware that this exposes your system to significant security risks.

Comment: Setting `security-enabled` to `false` in `broker.xml` will only impact _messaging_ clients. It won't impact _management_ clients (e.g. the web console).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).