# Embedded ActiveMQ Artemis web console loading incorrectly

Tags: java, activemq-artemis, hawtio

I am running an embedded instance of ActiveMQ Artemis and have been running into some trouble getting the web console to behave correctly.

In order to get the console to run I followed [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76670206/embedded-activemq-artemis-doesnt-show-web-console).

This successfully starts the console and I can login based on the username and password I set in my `login.config` file. However, when navigating through the console I noticed I am missing many of the navigation bars on the top of the console (queues, session, producers, etc.) as you can see in the image below and I'm not entirely sure why.

[image]

An additional problem that might help diagnose what is going on include the fact that just going to `consoleHost:8161` pulls up the below result but `consoleHost:8161/console` correctly redirects to the login page. However, these might be unrelated problems
[image]

Looking through the JavaScript files that are included in the decompressed `artemis-plugin.war` directory (specifically `\tmp\webapps\artemis-plugin.war\webapp\plugin\js\components\navigation.js`) I noticed that the inclusion of these are based on the MBean server so my leading theory is that instead of setting the MBean server to `ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer()` I should be setting it to something more specific to Artemis but I'm not sure what that would be.

Comparing the console logs of a locally running, standalone Artemis instance that correctly displays the console and my embedded implementation the only difference in initialization that stands out is that the working logs have the line:

```
[hawtio-jmx-rbac] Using mbean hawtio:type=security,area=jmx,name=ArtemisJMXSecurity for client-side role based access control
```

and my broken implementation instead has the line:

```
[hawtio-jmx-rbac] Using mbean hawtio:type=security,area=jmx,rank=0,name=HawtioDummyJMXSecurity for client-side role based access control
```

Not sure if any of this helps but any pointers to what could be wrong would be greatly appreciated as I have been scratching my head for awhile trying to get the console to work correctly on my embedded artemis instance.

EDIT:

Updating my answer with the code I added to the [original instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76670206/embedded-activemq-artemis-doesnt-show-web-console)

```
ActiveMQSecurityManager securityManager = server.getActiveMQServer().getSecurityManager();
ManagementContextDTO managementDTO = new ManagementContextDTO();
ManagementContext managementContext = ManagementFactory.create(managementDTO, securityManager);
server.getActiveMQServer().getManagementService().registerHawtioSecurity(managementContext.getArtemisMBeanServerGuard());
```

I placed these lines after the line `webServerDTO.addBinding(bindingDTO);` and before `webServerComponent.configure(webServerDTO, pathToArtemis, pathToArtemis);`

I believe this just enables default security configuration as I never defined a `management.xml` file but hopefully this is enough to help anyone with the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The artemis plugin requires a running ManagementContext, you can extract the steps to start the ManagementContext from https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/blob/2.32.0/artemis-cli/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/artemis/cli/commands/Run.java#L86

The console supports the `rootRedirectLocation` attribute to set the location to redirect the requests with the root target, see https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/web-server.html#embedded-web-server

Comment: Thank you! Updated my question with the lines I had to add

Comment: I think it would be nice if there were an error log for this or some pointer, as it is quite difficult to figure out that this is the root cause as-is.