# ActiveMQ Artemis Web Console missing tabs for producers, consumers, etc. when embedded?

Tags: activemq-artemis, hawtio

Currently the ActiveMQ Artemis web console shows exactly the same thing when I run embedded vs. through the executable, except in embedded mode I do not see a tab for "Connections", "Sessions", "Consumers", etc. I only see "Status", "Attributes", "Operations", "Charts", and "Broker Diagram" for the tabs.

I don’t see any super obvious errors in web console logs or failing fetch requests. I see we successfully XHR fetch the dependencies. Are there any obvious things to try?

I followed [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76689316/3813411) to get the web console up.

Comment: Please paste the code you're using to configure & start the embedded broker.

Comment: Yes, that solved it! Thank you! Marked it as duplicate. I happened to set it up last week before the additional instructions were added, and didn’t realize they had changed to reflect the addition.